# Lottery - guess correct number

Tags: java, if-statement, random

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
Random random = new Random();
System.out.print("Enter a number u wish(1-1000): ");
int unos = input.nextInt();
int rand = random.nextInt(1000) + 1;
System.out.println(rand);
if (unos = random) {
    System.out.printf("Congratz u won");
}
while (unos < rand) {
    System.out.println("Your number is lower \t Try again: ");
    unos = input.nextInt();
}
while (unos > rand) {
    System.out.println("Your number is higher\t Try again: ");
    unos = input.nextInt();
}
```

So, if I hit numbers that aren't equal to the randomly generated number it works, but once I hit, it doesn't output "Congratz u won". It just terminates. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Lutrija {

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random random = new Random();
        System.out.print("Uneti broj koji mislite da ce ispasti(1-1000): ");
        int unos=input.nextInt();
        int rand =random.nextInt(1000)+1;
        System.out.println(rand);
        while (unos!=rand){
            if(unos==rand){
                System.out.println("Congratz");
            }
            else if (unos>rand){
                System.out.println("broj je veci od izvucenog");
                unos=input.nextInt();
            }
            else if (unos<rand){
                System.out.println("broj je manji od izvucenog");
                unos=input.nextInt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, why?

Comment: Don't use `printf()` if you are not using format specifiers (e.g. `%s, %f, ...`)

Comment: Is this your real code? I'm asking because you claim you are able to run it, while I am not able to compile it because `(unos = random)` would return `int` instead of `boolean` (if comparing `int` with `Random` would be possible). Which version of Java you are using?

Comment: Great, you fixed the `==`. Now fix the loops.

Comment: adn you still have 3 instanes of `rand`in there. WHich is why it won'T compile on ANY java version.

Comment: @Pshemo it should read `(unos == rand)`, I believe he/she made a typo

Comment: @user3299707 Thanks for updating your Q, but please don't take the feedback as negative. We're all trying to help you learn, some people give feedback for frankly then others but don't let that discourage you from learning. If the answer helps you, please mark as correct so others can benefit from your question.

Comment: @user3299707 Why doesn't it work? Please be specific so we can help. Appears to work to me.

Comment: I've tryed this second code, and still it doesnt write the the result of Congratz if i type the corrent number

Answer (score 5):

You are using assignment `=` instead of equality test `==` in your if statement. Change to:

```
while ((unos = input.nextInt()) != rand) {
   // Tell them higher of lower
   // No need to call input.nextInt() in loop body as it is called
   //  when reevaluating while condition
}
// Congratulate them since to get here, unos == rand
```

You also should embody your code in a single loop that loops until guess equals the random number otherwise it just terminates as none of the `while` conditions will hold.

Comment: i listened to you but theres an error in ur code,it wont work because in while loop it wont get to if(unos==rand) in while (unos != rand) {
   if (unos == rand) {

Comment: @user3299707 it will miss it if by chance `unos==rand` on initialization of your variables. I recommend setting initial value of unos to something guaranteed to be different i.e. -1 and having the input of the integer in the while loop.

Comment: @user3299707 True. Move `if (unos == rand) {(System.out.println("Congratz");}` out of loop and get rid of `if` because it would be redundant now. Also `do{read()}while(x!=y)` seems more appropriate here than `read(); while(x!=y){tests,,, readAgain()}`.

Comment: @Pshemo good point, I've updated the answer per your suggestion.

Comment: @xlm You are not storing anywhere users value. You probably wanted `while ((unos = input.nextInt()) != rand)`

Comment: @user3299707 Great! Glad it worked, please mark as correct if it solved your problem. Also please note Pshemo's point about `while ((unos = input.nextInt()) != rand)`. This works because the returned value from an assignment is the value assigned. So `unos` is assigned the next input and that value is then compared to `rand`